# Colored border around multiple plots

Tags: r, plot, background-color

I would like to draw a colored border around each plot-window of a multiplot. Consider the following example:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

plot(1, 1)
plot(1, 1)
plot(1, 1)
plot(1, 1)
```

Output:

[image]

However, the multiplot should look as follows:

[image]

How could I do that in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to simply use `box()` function after every plot. In order to get different line thickness, I used two arguments: `"outer"` and `"figure"` which specifies where to draw the box.

So the code looks like this

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

plot(1, 1)
box("outer", col="green4", lwd = 30) # lwd - line tickness/width

plot(1, 1)
box("figure", col="green4",  lwd = 5)  

plot(1, 1)
box("figure", col="green4",  lwd = 5)

plot(1, 1)
box("outer", col="green4",  lwd = 30)
```

And the output:

[image]